# VS2022 versus VS2019: How/Why are the additional tasks being created?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

When Executing the following code in VS 2022 Community(version 17.8.3):

```
using static System.Console;

Action action1 = new(() => WriteLine($"Executing {Task.CurrentId}"));
Action action2 = new(() => WriteLine($"Executing {Task.CurrentId}"));
Action action3 = new(() => WriteLine($"Executing {Task.CurrentId}"));
Parallel.Invoke(action1, action2, action3);
```

are producing output like:

```
Executing 9
Executing 10
Executing 8
```

I understand that the id can change. But I never saw the id starts from 1. My friends report the same. They also add that the same code in VS 2019 was able to produce ids like 1,2, and 3 on multiple try.
**And here are the summarised observation:**

```
1.VS2019-debug and release- You can see IDs 1,2,3 etc
2.VS 2022 release- Same observation.
3.VS2022-Debug- IDs start appearing as 8,9,10; 9,10,11 or 10,11,12 ,and so on…
```

I posted the question on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Seems-like-TaskCurrentId-does-not-gener/10432547. Following the suggestion, I started debugging the code and found that some additional task ids were created due to this setting. Obviously, those additional task ids were not created when I ran the code in release configuration.  But I could not figure out how to avoid the creational process of those additional tasks in debug mode in VS2022.
Here are my questions:
1.Is the changed behavior an expected behavior?
2. is there any simple way to avoid the creational process of those additional tasks in debug mode in VS2022? If so, how?

Comment: Why is it important to you whether the VS debugger creates some tasks during initialization? If your code is sensitive to that, that feels like a problem in itself.

Comment: @Jon: Its not the problem for me; rather, I'd say that I was curious to see the behavior difference between the versions.Unfortunately, I could not find any documentation that specifically talks about this change. In fact, I have not found any article yet on this. But I assume that there must be some thoughts behind this change.I'd be happy to know about that. At the same time, I want to ensure that I am not the only person who is noticing this change.

Comment: "But I assume that there must be some thoughts behind this change." I doubt it. I strongly suspect it's just a matter of "launching the debugger happens to create a task in order to do something." I doubt that it's a deliberate "we're going to make the IDs start from a higher number" but a side-effect of something entirely different. I really would just ignore it if I were you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by [hot reload](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-hot-reload/) functionality as far as I can see.

If you place breakpoint at the start of the app and will go to the Parallel Stacks window (Debug -> Windows -> Parallel Stacks, switch to task view) you can see something like:

[image]

With some stackframes referring to stuff from `Microsoft.Extensions.HotReload` namespace.

You can try disabling the hot reload: go to the project properties -> Debug -> Open debug launch profiles UI -> uncheck Enable Hot Reload option:

[image]

[image]

This results in "correct" task ids for me.

Comment: It answers my questions.Thanks for the reply.